# Ethernet connection dropping - DHCP issue?

Tags: networking, routing, dhcp

A user with a Fedora installation is experiencing intermittent interruptions to his wired internet connection on the LAN.  I've swapped cables and ports and double checked my VLANS and switchport configuration.  When the users internet connection is interrupted, he can still ping the gateway on the subnet, but not the DHCP servers that are on a different subnet.

One thing seems to stand out; the laptop he is using was once assigned an IP address using a DHCP reservation on that subnets scope.  The reservation has since been deleted, but the users computer is still assigned the address that was once used for that DHCP reservation.

So far the solution has been to manually bring down and bring up the users network interface and that is the workaround.  The wireless interface on the same machine seems to work fine, and is assigned a lower metric than the wired interface in the routing table.

Comment: Since it's still assigned the old IP address by an unreachable DHCP server and you've deleted the reservation, why not just set the address, gateway and DNS manually (static)? Then there's no confusion about what automatic settings may or may not be applied when the internet drops.

Comment: When DHCP clients request an address they tell the DHCP server which address they last had, and if the DHCP can give it to them (same subnet, no other device using it, etc.) it will.  DHCP is only used for getting an address, outside of that the DHCP server is not used by the clients, and it will have no effect on them.  Your problem (whatever it is) is not caused by DHCP -- sounds more like a routing failure.

Comment: We did "sudo dhclient" but I'm realizing now that without specifying an interface it may have picked the wireless interface, if this is in fact some weird problem with having the address it does.